# DOM not reflecting updated resultset

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2.

I had some code working perfectly, then after updating to cordova from 6.3.0 to 6.3.1, it doesn't work anymore. I tried downgrading back to 6.3.0. but it still does not work. However, I think my code should work with 6.3.1, so I am probably doing something incorrect in my code.

I have a list of items, and then when I update the list, the DOM is not reflecting the update.

There are 2 issues here:

1. The first time I access the page from the menu, it returns 15 rows,
   and displays them correctly. However I then access the page with a
   parameter (employeeModel) from another page (cat.ts) and the JSON
   call only returns 3 rows, but the DOM is displayed before the JSON
   call returns and displays 15 rows.
2. cat.ts passes a parameter employeeModel to search.ts. In seach.ts
   constructor, the employeeModel parameter is populated, but when a
   button click calls presentPopover the employeeModel parameter is
   undefined.

**search.html**

```
...
    <div id="pinButton"><button (click)="presentPopover()" secondary><ion-icon name="funnel"></ion-icon></button></div>
...
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of employeeModels">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-row >
          <ion-col><h2>{{item.firstName}}</h2></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
       </ion-item>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

**search.ts**

```
...
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/search/search.html',
  providers: [EmployeeService, UtilityService],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class SearchPage {
...
  private employeeModel: EmployeeModel;
  private employeeModels: EmployeeModel[] = [];
...
  constructor(ref: ChangeDetectorRef, nav: NavController, employeeService: EmployeeService, utilityService: UtilityService, private navParams: NavParams, private popoverController: PopoverController) {
    this.ref = ref;
    this.nav = nav;
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
    this.utilityService = utilityService;
    this.employeeModel = navParams.get('employeeModel');
    console.log(this.employeeModel);
    this.getEmployeeRange();
  }
...
  getEmployeeRange() {
    console.log(this.employeeModel);
    this.searchLoading = true;
    var promise: Promise<EmployeeModel[]>;
    promise = this.employeeService.getEmployeeRangeSearch(this.firstResult, this.MAX_RESULTS, this.getSubCategoryString())
    promise.then((employeeModels: EmployeeModel[]) => {
      for (var index = 0; index < employeeModels.length; index++) {
        this.employeeModels.push(employeeModels[index]);
      }
      console.log(this.employeeModels.length);
      this.searchLoading = false;
      this.ref.markForCheck();
    });
  }

  presentPopover(event: Event) {
    console.log('presentPopover: '+this.employeeModel);
    console.log(this.employeeModel);
    let popover: Popover = this.popoverController.create(SearchPopOverPage, {employeeModel: this.employeeModel});
    popover.present();
  }
```

**cat.ts**

```
console.log(this.employeeModel);
  this.nav.insert(0, SearchPage, {
    employeeModel: this.employeeModel,
  }).then(() => {
    const index = this.nav.getActive().index;
    this.nav.remove(index - 1);
  });
```

Comment: I have tried removing `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` with the same problems occurring.

Comment: I also try the following with no success:  `this.zone = new NgZone({ enableLongStackTrace: false });

    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.getEmployeeRange();
    });`

Comment: This works

`this.nav.insert(0, SearchPage, {
employeeModel: this.employeeModel
})`
Problem is the navbar icon does display correctly but when clicked does nothing instead of launch the menu.